# How to cancel a bootstrap overriding?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

In my css file,   i've overriden a bootstrap uib-tooltip class . This applies to all tooltips of my page but i want that one of them  uses the bootstrap default css , how to do that? The :not selector didn't work

Comment: I wonder why `:not` selector does not work for you, can you please share a code snippet of what you've done?

Comment: https://codepen.io/khaledmoez/pen/MdZQej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your pen, You need to use

```
div:not(.kmg)>.text-primary{
   color:red !important;
}
```

See the codepen here

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQbJKb

Comment: Indeed. Thank you very much.